# filter string in comprehension list with nested loops

Tags: python

I want just for fun know if it's possible process this in a comprehension 
list
some like:

```
text = "give the most longest word"
def LongestWord(text):
    l = 0
    words = list()
    for x in text.split():
        word = ''.join(y for y in x if y.isalnum())
        words.append(word)
    for word in words:
        if l < len(word):
            l = len(word)
            r = word
    return r
```

Comment: Add a sample value for text argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not one but two list comprehensions:

```
s = 'ab, c d'
cmpfn = lambda x: -len(x)
sorted([''.join(y for y in x if y.isalnum()) for x in s.split()], key=cmpfn)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Zero list comprehensions:

```
import re
def longest_word(text):
    return sorted(re.findall(r'\w+', text), key=len, reverse=True)[0]

print(longest_word("this is an example.")) # prints "example"
```

Or, if you insist, the same thing but with a list comprehension:

```
def longest_word(text):
    return [w for w in sorted(re.findall(r'\w+', text), key=len, reverse=True)][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a list comprehension, really.

```
import re
my_longest_word =  max(re.findall(r'\w+', text), key=len)
```

Alternatively if you ***don't*** want to `import re`, you can avoid a lambda expression and use one list comprehension using `max` once again:

```
my_longest_word =  max([ ''.join(l for l in word if l.isalnum()) 
                     for w in text.split() ], key = len)
```

**How this works:**

- Uses a list comprehension and `isalnum()` to filter out non-alphanumeric characters evaluating each letter in each word, and splits into a list using whitespaces.
- Takes the `max` once again.

**How regex solution works:**

- Matches all alphanumeric of at least length 1 with `\w+`
- `findall()` places the matches in a list of strings
- `Max` finds the element with maximum length from the list.

**Outputs (*in both cases*):**

```
>>>text = "give the most longest word"
>>>my_longest_word
'longest'
>>>text = "what!! is ??with !@#$ these special CharACTERS?"
>>>my_longest_word
'CharACTERS'
```

Comment: This question born me by the codebyte.com challenge and the interpreter don't have "import modules" feature implemented or something, thanks

Comment: @mnothic Ahh, I fixed my non-regex answer to filter out special characters, if that matters to you.